# JavaFX project Jar doesnt run because it cant load main class NetBeans and an issue importing other modules

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, build, ant

Ive been working on a project that uses javaFX for the UI as well as various other modules for other functionality, the project compiles but when I try to run the jar I get the following error [Cmd Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zga3W.png)

The project uses Ant with the following things in the module info file [Module-info.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfAxP.png)

I also have another issue with the project, I am adding javaFX through the module path, as well as all of the other modules im using but some of them arent being detected such as these [Not working Imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYOjh.png)

Here are screenshots of how I set everything up
[Jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHGP0.png)

[How I added the JavaFX lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Td0.png)

[SRC of javafx in lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkYN2.png)

Please let me know if I should provide any other information

Comment: I'm not sure, try make a file `src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` with content `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: your.main.class`, and rebuild it

Comment: So I just tried doing that and its the same error, could it be because my project has a different name from the package that contains all of the classes?

Comment: Have you run the project successfully with the IDE?
I'm not a netbean expert.  Let's try with a simple project

Comment: Sorry for the late response, yes the project runs inside the ide, so I took your advice and made a simple javafx project and ran it in the ide perfefctly fine and the same error occurred when I tried to run the jar, I think my issue is that im not adding the javafx properly, or that im missing something when building that adds the module to the jar

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix all of this by taking all javafx and all of other modules off of modulepath in libraries and adding them to classpath, then I had my main and start in one class so I put the main method in a separate launch class that doesnt extend application and changed launch() to Application.launch(Main.class, args), I also changed the vm options in run to include javafx.graphics in the --add-module this fixed all of the issues I was having, please leave a comment if someone needs more information